# How to access all the attributes of a trigger of task scheduler

Tags: c#, .net

I want to compare the values present in the trigger of a task, for e.g. months of year, days of week, which week these values need to be accessed in order to compare them. I can get to know whether the task is enable or not using Task.Definition.Triggers[0].Enabled, but How can I get months, which week and other details!?

Comment: what you are talking about. Something like this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/tasks ? Can you please add more context to your request, so that people not sitting next to your monitor knows what you are doing ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.